# BOOTP/DHCP that can be restricted to one network card

Tags: windows, networking

I'm looking for a BOOTP/DHCP Utility similar to the one from [Rockwell Automation](http://www.ab.com/linked/networks/ethernet/bootp.html) that can be restricted to one network card. I have multiple network interfaces on my PC, and I have a need to be connected to our corporate network while supplying a BOOTP/DHCP service to assign IP addresses to various devices. I would only be working with one device at a time and I want it to only work on the network card I'm using to configure the device so I don't interfere with our corporate DHCP service. My search attempts on Google haven't turned up anything, so maybe someone else on here knows of one that I've overlooked or that hasn't turned up.

- The utility needs to work on Windows XP, and/or Windows 7 x64.
- Can be GUI or command line driven.
- Free and open source would be preferred, but at this point I'd accept any recommendations that are under $100.

Comment: are you still looking for this?

Comment: yes, do you know of any?

Comment: No I don't but how much C#/programming do you know? I can give you a breakdown of the code. I just programmed something similar for my workplace.

Answer (score 1):

[WinGate](http://www.wingate.com) has a DHCP server, and you can specify which interfaces it will bind to.

The DHCP service does not use license counts, so the free 10 user license will probably work for this.

Disclaimer: I work for Qbik who are the authors of WinGate.